# How to avoid CORS and use proxy when deploying on netlify with Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, cors, netlify

Hope the question is clear as I don't really know what's going on.

MERN app recently stopped working exactly after adding proxy and trying to fix CORS.
I had a api end point variable 'API_URL' and all my requests were like this

```
axios.get(`${API_URL}/api/users)
```

at first I sat a proxy on the react package.json to

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5001",
```

so I can change all my request calls to be like this

```
axios.get('/api/users')
```

and I also deleted my origin allow custom func :-

```
originAllow = (app) => {
  app.all("*", function (req, res, next) {
    if (!req.get("Origin")) return next();
    res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, PATCH");
    res.set(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
      "X-Requested-With,Content-Type,x-auth-token"
    );
    next();
  });
};
originAllow(app);
```

everything is working perfect locally but when I deploy it to Netlify the website crashes with error -> **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')** which is basically because it cannot request data from the api so my arrays are empty and there is nothing to map.

later on I tried

```
"proxy": "https://madevmeet.herokuapp.com",
```

also works perfect locally but when I deploy it same error.

I tried to install CORS package as well and use it in my backend , redeploy it to Heroku and Netlify and I still get the same error. it is driving me nuts.
and again everything is working fine locally.

what have I missed ?
I can restore everything to the point were it did work and with API variable but I'm sure I'm missing something.

thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

Solution : I’v added to _redirects in client the lines :
`/api/* https://mysite.herokuapp.com/:splat 200`

and a procfile in the server with the lines:
`web:node server.js`